Water Pump cycles on/off every few minutes
I have a water well system with FP7105-8 2 gallon inline tank. I noticed the water pump cycles every few minutes, so I tried measuring the tank pressure, but there is none. Next, I tried just pushing the pin, but here is no air coming out. I figure the main problem is the valve, so I want to replace it first.
Am I correct to think that if there is no air in the thank, there is a leak and the valve looks like a good approach?
What do you recommend I check?
Thanks

What you are experiencing is relatively common in well systems in which the pressure tank has lost pressure in the bladder. With the pump power turned off, use an air pump or air compressor to load the tank through the valve to the pressure recommended for your system, helpful guide here.
When the pump starts, it should fill the tank until the water pressure reaches the cut-off point, at which time the pump will stop. During use, the water will exit the tank, lowering the pressure until it reaches the cut-in point, starting the pump again.
You can check for a leaky valve by applying soapy water and looking for bubbles. If you see any, use a valve stem tool to tighten the core, possibly eliminating that problem.
If none of this is helpful, you may have a bladder leak, which would require the replacement of the tank.

Just adding: if you follow these good instructions and notice that occasional spurts of air start coming out of faucets when you run water, that is another sign of a bladder leak and a reason to replace the pressure tank.
